# Почему не отображается цвет Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Не отображается Frame и текстовые виджеты

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

fra=Frame(root,height=500,width=500,bg='lightgreen')
fra.pack()


tex1=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex1.pack()

tex2=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что должен продемонстрировать данный код?

Comment: Ошибочка не тот код

Comment: скобки в `fra.pack` поставьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас фрейм ужимается до размера текстовых полей, поэтому его фон не виден. Добавьте `fra.pack_propagate(False)`, чтобы это не происходило:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

fra=Frame(root,height=500,width=500,bg='lightgreen')
fra.pack_propagate(False)
fra.pack()


tex1=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex1.pack()

tex2=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

И, кстати, lightgreen - это светлозелёный, а не голубой.

[image: Скриншот]